# window.document.body.appendChild(child); redundant in the page for each iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a Chrome extension developer, I have a problem in my extension which is:
When I create an element

```
child = document.createElement('div');
```

and add this element to the page body:

```
window.document.body.appendChild(child);
```

for pages that contains several iFrames, this child appears in every iFrame in the page.

How can I force this element to appear only in the main window, not on all iframes?

thanks.

Comment: What about removing `window.`?

Comment: it was without window, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you turn the "all_frames" value to false in **manifest** and check(meaning that only the top frame is matched.)

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      .....
      "all_frames":false
      .....
    }
  ],
```

### Reference:

[Manifest for Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration)

#### EDIT 1:

Split your content script code into two parts where

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [".."],
      "all_frames":true,
      "js": ["myscript_iframes.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": [".."],
      "all_frames":false,
      "js": ["myscript_noIframes.js"]
    }
  ],
```

`myscript_iframes.js` has code where you read content from all frames and `myscript_noIframes.js` has code where you append child to main frame.

Comment: If I check that option, my extension will not function very well, I need to read text from all iFrames, but I want to append to the main window document.

Comment: @kdureidy:Check my edit, content scripts can share variables between scripts, so redundancy and duplication can be avoided.